# How to get version number in index.html using React with Vite?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vite

I want to create a `<meta>` element in my index.html containing the current app version like so:

```
<meta name="version" content="1.0.0" />
```

Where the version number should be coming from my `package.json` file.

Is this possible to do in a simple way when using React and Vite?

Answer (score -2):

#### Try this first

Add the version to your .env

```
APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

then in your app

```
<meta name="version content={import.meta.env.APP_VERSION} />
```

If that doesn't work and you don't mind exposing the package.json

```js
// you may have to go up or down a directory
// I don't know your app structure

import packageJson from '/package.json';

<meta name="version content={packageJson.version} />
```

### Update

Try to add this in your app.js file

```js
const useAppVersion = () => {
    useEffect(() => {  
      document.querySelector("meta[name='version']").setAttribute("content", import.meta.env.APP_VERSION || '1.0.0);
    }, []);
};

function App() {
  usePageMeta();
  return (
  ... rest of your app here ...
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you get the `import.meta.env.APP_VERSION` value in index.html? When I try what you said i just get this tag in my header: `<meta name="version" content="{import.meta.env.APP_VERSION}">`

Comment: Shouldn't `usePageMeta()` in the updated example down there be `useAppVersion()` instead?